# Problem with fourier font using xelatex and lualatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, fontspec, fourier

I have a problem with `œ` and `Œ` unicode characters using `fourier` with `xelatex` and `lualatex`. When I compile with `pdflatex` (with `[T1]{fontenc}` and `[utf8]{inputenc}`) everything is ok.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec} % pour le bon encodage des PDFs => police lmodern
% ---------------
\usepackage{fourier}
% ---------------

\begin{document}

  œ, Œ, æ, Æ

  Opération à c{\oe}ur ouvert.
  Autres temps, autres mœurs.
  Œdipe.

  Ædes.
  Penitusque cavæ plangoribus ædes femineis ululant.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have found how to overcome this using `newunicodechar` package :

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec} % pour le bon encodage des PDFs => police lmodern
% ---------------
\usepackage{fourier}
% correct the bug with xe/lualatex
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{œ}{\oe}
\newunicodechar{Œ}{\OE}
% ---------------

\begin{document}

  œ, Œ, æ, Æ

  Opération à c{\oe}ur ouvert.
  Autres temps, autres mœurs.
  Œdipe.

  Ædes.
  Penitusque cavæ plangoribus ædes femineis ululant.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**My question is :** Is this a known (or unknown) bug or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the fourier package to setup the text font with xelatex and lualatex. It switches to T1 encoding which isn't sensible for this engines.

You can use it to change the math setup, but for the text use e.g. heuristica:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fourier} %before fontspec
\usepackage{fontspec} % pour le bon encodage des PDFs => police lmodern
\setmainfont{Heuristica}
% ---------------
%
% ---------------

\begin{document}

  œ, Œ, æ, Æ

  Opération à c{\oe}ur ouvert.
  Autres temps, autres mœurs.
  Œdipe.

  Ædes.
  Penitusque cavæ plangoribus ædes femineis ululant.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't it necessary then to load `fontspec` with the `no-math` option?

Comment: @FranckPastor it is not necessary but it can make a difference.

Comment: How so? I thought that without this option, it was the Latin Modern math fonts that were loaded by `fontspec`.

Comment: @FranckPastor No. You can check it in a minimal example with lualatex: `$\int x=y$` will still use cmex and cmmi. But fontspec changes some math alphabets (e.g. \mathrm).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer and why Æ is working but not Œ ? And why the font is looking like fourier if it is not ?

Comment: Æ  is in unicode at position C6 and in T1 too. But Œ is in unicode at (hex) 152 and in T1 at position D7. heuristica is a clone of fourier.

Comment: `Erewhon` is more complete than `Heuristica`, as far as I know.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the explanation, this make sens now for me.

Comment: @Bernard thanks to pointing to `Erewhon`.

Comment: Another way to work with both `fourier` and LuaLaTeX would be not to load `fontspec` but to insert `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` instead. This is mostly useful for compatibility with old documents. I suppose XeLaTeX has a similar package. But indeed it makes little sense to use LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX without `fontspec` for new documents, unless, in the cas of LuaLaTeX, you want to use some peculiar LuaTeX facilities in old documents. Inserting Lua or MetaPost code, for example.